# Firestore database cloud function trigger multiple times

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am doing a mobile app which talks to Firestore database. What I found is that if I manually changes the data at Firestore database, my local app Firestore cloud function (Observable, getting docData for example) will be triggered multiple times, at least twice, sometimes three times.

Can someone give me a hint how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you have and the specific instructions of what you're doing that causes the unexpected behavior.  Your code should be a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example), and we should be able to copy your code and instructions to observe the same result.  Without this, there's not much we can do to help because we can't see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I figured out what was the issue. It was not triggered from firestore. It is multiple subscribes. I added code to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy().